# navigation drawer header is over the content?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-xml

I'm trying to add a header in my navigation drawer.
I'm a beginner on android studio, so any tips would help me a lot

The problem is this header is over my navigation drawer itens, so I can't see some of my navigation drawer itens.

how can I add this header properly? also, my textview content is not showing, why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.sk.mf.UserAreaActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame">
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@layout/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/nh_User"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </RelativeLayout>






    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the Header in header tag of `NavigationView`:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"  //layout of Header
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />
```

in your `layout/nav_header.xml`: add the header contents

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_header" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To access the Header layout contents use:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);  //get the header view
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nh_User);
text.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: thank you friend! So my textview would be in nav_header.xml too? Doing it how can I add a text in the textview inside the header dinamically? because I have a  `setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);` for this xml and `nh_User.setText(Username);` to add some text in this textview, but creation a nav_header.xml I cannot refer to `nh_User` anymore...

Comment: is it posible get this views with butterknife?

Comment: can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593446/accessing-navigation-header-elements-using-butterknife  @Ricardo